# Need to give home folder directory path in groovy script

Tags: java, groovy

I'm having the groovy script of Import the DTD's Schema. I'm having that particular DTD schema file in certain path (D:/homefolder/doctypes/dtd/import.dtd). In the groovy script, I'm directly specified the path name.

```
import com.reallysi.rsuite.admin.importer.*
import com.reallysi.rsuite.client.api.*

def projectDir = new File('D:/homefolder/')
def doctypesDir = new File(projectDir, "doctypes");
def srcDir = new File(projectDir, "src");
```

But I need the corresponding doctype folder fetch by using home folder directory path which having the build files. Not like the directly mentioning the path in the script

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: @daggett I have tried this. But It's going to the C:\user. But I want to go project directory

Comment: maybe you just need current directory? `new File(".")`

Comment: @daggett I have use this, but it's going to the place where my groovy script are there.

Comment: the current folder you define when you starting java process. and you could define current dir (start dir) in your project.